# How to integrate $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4})}{\rm d}x$ using substitution $x = \frac{\pi}{2} - y$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I reached
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x) + \sin(x)}{\rm d}x
 = \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(y)}{\cos(y) + \sin(y)}{\rm d}y
$$ by using the double angle formula and the substitution but not sure how the question wants me to "exploit the symmetry at the midpoint." Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let$$I:=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin x{\rm d}x}{\sin(x+\pi/4)}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt{2}\sin x{\rm d}x}{\sin x+\cos x}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sqrt{2}\cos y{\rm d}y}{\sin y+\cos y}$$
so, averaging the last two expressions,$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\pi/2}{\rm d}x=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{8}}.$$